# Uncaught TypeError: SpeechRecognition is not a constructor at app.js:5

Tags: javascript, html, ecmascript-6, speech-recognition

I'm coding a voice reconition assitant to make it work in my web page but I got this error: Uncaught TypeError: SpeechRecognition is not a constructor     at app.js:5(I'm using Google Chrome browser).

```js
const btn = document.querySelector('.talk');
const content = document.querySelector('.content');

const SpeechRecognition = window.SpeechRecognition || window.webkitSpeechrecognition;
const recognition = new SpeechRecognition(); 

recognition.onstart = function() {
   console.log('Voice Is Activated, You Can Speak');
};

recognition.onresult = function(event) {
   console.log(event);
};

btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
   recognition.start();
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
   <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
      <title>MY ASSISTANT</title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <h1>Hello World</h1>
      <img src="#" alt=""></img>
      <button class="talk">Talk</button>
      <h1 class="content"></h1>

      <script src="app.js"></script>
   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 5):

You need to make sure you keep the correct capitaliazation - it's `webkitSpeechRecognition` (uppercased `R`).

```js
const SpeechRecognition = window.speechRecognition || window.webkitSpeechRecognition;
console.log(new SpeechRecognition());
```

Comment: @JackBashford Thanks alot bro. It worked well. It was a little error lol.

Comment: Pretty sure it should be `window.SpeechRecognition || window.webkitSpeechRecognition` when official support is available. I doubt a constructor would be camel-case without the vendor prefix. The [examples](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SpeechRecognition#Examples) on MDN seem to agree.

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution, let the variable be webkitSpeechRecognition, without || operator. Because Google actually uses this constructor with a prefix `WebKit`.

Answer (score 0):

if you are running in firefox so speechRecognition not supported on

Comment: Hi All in one, thanks for contributing. The poster of this question wrote that this issue was for Google Chrome and seemingly also the right solution has been given. Please also properly format your answers with the proper punctuation and capitalization next time.

Comment: @Ansjovis86: yes, but actually other users are using Firefox. The question does not tag Chrome, this info is just added between parenthesis for info.

Answer (score 0):

`SpeechRecognition` does not exist.

Try using `webkitSpeechRecognition`.It worked for me.

*This is for Chrome browser clients*

Comment: this is for chrome browser clients